# Memory Leak in this short method

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

Instruments is reporting all the leaks of this VC in this method. What could be the reason? I think it's the alloc, but don't know why is leaking.

```
- (void)loadViewContent
{
    switch (self.currentView) 
    {
        case 0:
            self.title = @"Title 1";
            [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem release]; //para evitar un memory leak
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blood" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                                     target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

            [tableContent addObject:@"0"];
            [tableContent addObject:@"1 - 49"];
            [tableContent addObject:@"50 - 75"];
            [tableContent addObject:@"76 - 89"];
            [tableContent addObject:@"More than 89"];
            break;

        case 1: 
            self.title = @"Title 2";
            [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem release]; 
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Resp. Rate" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                                     target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

            [tableContent addObject:@"0"];
            [tableContent addObject:@"1 - 5"];
            [tableContent addObject:@"6 - 9"];
            [tableContent addObject:@"More than 29"];
            [tableContent addObject:@"10 - 29"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the output from the leaks tool?  Perhaps there are some more clues there.

Comment: I've added a screen of the output. Do you mean that output? (sorry I'm new at instruments)

Comment: Ok. That helps a little.  We're looking for (2) 32 byte objects.

Comment: What's the purpose of `[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem release];`?  That's not normal.

Comment: Just trying to fix the leaks. Doesnt work. I've deleted the alloc lines and the leaks still remains. It's seems that the problem is the array...

Comment: you should consider doing a printout of your retainCount and making sure you don't have additional references that aren't being released somewhere.  If your retainCount is anything other than 1 before you call release, you may have found an issue.

Comment: I think the problem is the array because now I've tried this in the dealloc method:     NSLog(@"RETAIN COUNT %i",[tableContent retainCount]);
[tableContent release]; and retain is 2 before the release. The only place I use that array is in loadViewContent so I do not understand why it has a retain of 2 instead of 1. Maybe ViewDidLoad is the problem here? In viewDidLoad I create it like this: self.tableContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code definitely leaks (assuming a memory model of copy or retain on the property tableContent):

```
self.tableContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The setter of tableContent will release the old value and retain / copy / assign the new value.  Consider a statement like:

```
self.tableContent = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This is perfectly valid because [NSMutableArray array] is an autoreleased object.  Subsequent uses of self.tableContent only work after this because the setter of tableContent increments the retain count preventing tableContent from being released.

Your code (as weird as this seems) should be like the following:

```
self.tableContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.tableContent release];
```

OR      - requires using an autoreleased object which some devs like to avoid where possible

```
self.tableContent = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

OR      - uses an unnecessary temp variable to clarify memory management

```
NSMutableArray * tempArr = [NSMutableArray alloc];
self.tableContent = tempArr;
[tempArr release];
```

Comment: Forgot to ask, but did you run the static clang analyzer on your project?  I would've thought it would catch this.